# VSCode extension read current findInFiles panel's values/settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible, from within a vscode extension, to read all the findInFiles panel's options and input values?

The idea being that I'd like to add a function to my custom extension that can inspect the  findInFiles panel and give back what would essentially amount to a IFindInFilesArgs instance populated with all the values/settings currently defined in the panel (i.e. the search query, replace string, filesToInclude, filesToExclude, isRegex, isCaseSensitive, matchWholeWord).

Thanks for any direction or suggestions.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not possible.  And I could not find a related issue.